# Nodejs listing directories with child_process.spawn ends before receiving all data

Tags: node.js, cmd, multiprocessing, child-process, spawn

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function main() {
    ls = spawn('dir', {shell: true});
    ls.stdout.on('data', data => console.log('DATA RECEIVED'));
    ls.on('exit', code => console.log('EXITED'));
}

main();
```

This runs on Windows, and the result is

```
DATA RECEIVED
EXITED
DATA RECEIVED
```

Why is EXITED printed out before the last line? Is there any way safe to check whether all the data is received or not?

Comment: Nodejs  version?

Comment: node version v14.16.1